# How to determine number of appends when looping over list in Python?

Tags: python, loops, append

I have the following code:

```
lstcurrencies = ['btc', 'eth', 'usdt']
dict_lstlegacy_symbols = dict.fromkeys(lstcurrencies, []) # creates {'btc': [], 'eth': [], 'usdt': []}

for currency in lstcurrencies:
    print(currency)
    dict_lstlegacy_symbols[currency].append(1)
```

This creates the three lists:

```
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['btc']: [1, 1, 1]
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['eth']: [1, 1, 1]
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['usdt']: [1, 1, 1]
```

What I would actually like to get is:

```
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['btc']: [1]
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['eth']: [1]
dict_lstlegacy_symbols['usdt']: [1]
```

I don't understand why it adds the 1 three times instead of only one time. How can I obtain my desired result?

Comment: Because you have **exactly one** list in your dict, the list you passed to `dict.fromkeys`

Comment: so just create your dict like this: `{curr:[] for curr in lstcurrencies}`

Comment: I'd use [`dict_lstlegacy_symbols = defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use defualt dict instead.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lstcurrencies = ['btc', 'eth', 'usdt']
dict_lstlegacy_symbols =defaultdict(list) 

for currency in lstcurrencies:
    print(currency)
    dict_lstlegacy_symbols[currency].append(1)

print(dict_lstlegacy_symbols)
```